# How to pass argument in command line with npm and read it in react javascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I run the react application using `npm start` which in package.json is defined as `"start": "react-scripts start -o"`. in the js code I have

```
const backendUrl = 'hardCodedUrl';
```

I want this property to be passed as CLI argument. like:

```
npm start url=newUrl
```

and read this in the javascript code at runtime to be able to set backendUrl. How Can I do this?

Comment: [Here's some documentation that might help](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I visited the link Andy sent and here is how I did it:
Because I'm on Windows and using Terminal with PowerShell, run:

```
$env:REACT_APP_TT_BACKEND_URL = "Thank you Andy"
npm start
```

In the code

```
console.log('REACT_APP_TT_BACKEND_URL', process.env.REACT_APP_TT_BACKEND_URL);
```